# Javascript not taking day in Date() constructor correctly

Tags: javascript, date, express, momentjs

I am developing an API where a user can ask for transactions in a given year and month. The API looks like

```
routes.get('/transactions/:member_id/:year/:month', (req, res) => {
    let {member_id, year, month} = req.params;
    let start_date = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
    let end_date = moment(start_date).add(1, 'months');

    console.log({start_date, end_date});
    res.send({start_date, end_date})
});
```

I  am using `ExpressJS` to build API and `momentjs` to manipulate dates.

When I hit this api as  http://localhost:8080/transactions/m/2017/10, I ask transactions for user `m`, year `2017` and month `10` which is October (this is why I do `month - 1` in my implementation above).

What I get back in `console` is

```
{ start_date: 2017-09-30T11:00:00.000Z,
  end_date: moment("2017-11-01T00:00:00.000") }
```

I am confused because start day of the month has been hardcoded as `1`

```
let start_date = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
```

and not `30`. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Probably because you are specifying times in GMT, but the console output is in a different timezone.

Comment: That suggests your timezone is GMT+13? oh, wait ... or GMT+12 with summer time as of october 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an issue with the timezone. What you can do is:

```
let start_date = new Date(year, --month);
start_date.setUTCDate(1);
```

JavaScript Date() uses client local timezone. To get a consistent result, JavaScript Date() has utc methods to help standardize the date based on the GMT World Standard Time. Check [MDN's JavaScript Date Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Alternatively, you can also do this:

```
let start_date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, --month, 1));
```

Comment: Can you add references to back up your statement?

Comment: Thanks, but you should add this in your answer :)

Comment: No. Thank you. I should have done that. Thanks for pointing this one out. :)

Answer (score 0):

This does look like a timezone issue.

In your Client you can use `Date.prototype.getTimeZoneOffset()` and then add that to your date.
But you will have to add some time parameters to your url then.

Oh Time zones; though art a cold hearted mistress.